# How to enable javax annotations when value not null and disabled when value is null?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, annotations

I need to disable validation if the value of email is null and check on it if the value is not null.

```
@Email(message = "{invalidMail}")
private String email;
```

Comment: The hibernate `EmailValidator` will ignore `null` and empty values so basically it already does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and it's that almost all java validation annotations accepts null so if my value is null it's going to accept it otherwise it will check.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this result with the predefined set of validation annotations only.

You have to create a custom validation annotation which performs the validation based on the specifications. You can get inspired on the Baeldung's article [Spring MVC Custom Validation](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator).

Here is the annotation.

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyEmailValidator.class)     // Class which performsthe validation
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })                        // Applicable to a field
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyEmail {
    String message() default "The email is invalid";  // The default message
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And a class which actually performs the validation itself against the email Regex if the input is not null. Returns true otherwise as null is accepted. Note this class has to implement [`ConstraintValidator<A extends Annotation, T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html).

```
public class MyEmailValidatorimplements ConstraintValidator<MyEmail, String> {

    // Email Regex
    private final String emailPattern= "[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}";

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyEmail myEmail) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String input, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        if (input == null) {
            return true; 
        } else return Pattern.matches(emailPattern, input);
    }
}
```

Comment: The default Hibernate Validation `EmailValidator` already ignores `null` and empty values, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: that's will solve the case and that's what i did before i submit the question but this solution is not dynamic for example what about `@Min` or `@Max` or any validation annotation. 
Even if you made the regex a parameter so like that you replace all the validation annotations with your validation.